# Windows - "File not found" when calling a specific file from Lua only

Tags: windows, shell, lua, shellexecute

I copied the openvpn.exe file in the System32 directory. Now, if I go to the directory where the Lua file is saved and run

```
openvpn
```

I successfully get the help message, but if I run the Lua file with content:

```
os.execute("openvpn")
```

It gives the 'file not recognised as an internal ...' error. I also tried using `popen` or full path like this:

```
os.execute("%SystemRoot%\\System32\\openvpn.exe")
```

But it just keeps on giving the same error.

Comment: What is the full error message that you receive?

Comment: What if you try to start a windows program that's known to be in system32? For instance, `os.execute "calc"`?

Comment: Ryan Stein: "openvpn.exe is not recognised as an internal or external command or executable file." - I thought we all knew this.

Comment: greatwolf: I forgot to mention it works like that, it fails with openvpn.exe only.

Comment: I have openvpn and Lua has no problem launching it. Does your `%SystemRoot%` directory have spaces in the name (unlikely, but could cause this problem)? Have you tried running the first script (`os.execute("openvpn")`) *from* the System32 directory? Regarding the error message: the error message you showed Ryan is necessarily for the first script. What error does the *second* script show? That could reveal a path issue.

Comment: My %SystemRoot% value is "C:\Windows". And no, the second script shows just the same error. I also tried to `cd %SystemRoot%\\System32 & openvpn.exe` but I still get the `file not recognised as an internal or ...` error.

Comment: Have you tried this with anything other than Lua, such as Python or C?

Comment: @noize Sounds like it's finding the file, then, but not recognizing it as an executable. Have you done "where openvpn" to ensure your raw command line test is executing the file in system32? More troubleshooting: try `os.execute("cmd /c openvpn")` or create a batch file that executes that, then use `os.execute` on the batch file. Not as a final solution, mind you, but as a troubleshooting step. Perhaps there is some bizarre reason Lua can't execute that file, but a batch file should be able to, and `cmd.exe` should be able to, and Lua should be able to launch those.

Comment: Tried with Python `os.system("openvpn")` and it works fine. With Lua `cmd /c openvpn` fails just as well. I'm not sure of what's the matter here, I just copied the file to the parent directory and using that path it works, so I'll be using this solution for now. I'd still love to hear your opinion if you're sure you know what's going on here.